# Ember randomly fails {{render}} partial - How should I proceed?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

When I initiate my ember application (inside of an phonegap application) it sometimes fails to render my main navigation partial.

It happens very rarely, but when it does I have to terminate the process before it reappears.

How can I deal with this in a good way? Should I listen for its insertion and if it doesn't happen, insert it? How do I do that programmatically?

I'm using ember 1.0.0-rc.2.

NEVERMIND: Turns out it did render, but my stateManager failed to add a class to activate it. Solved it by looking checking if it actually was added and if not, adding it again.

Comment: have you tried updating you ember.js version to the latest?

Comment: @intuitivepixel They've made some breaking changes in the latest releases and our deadline doesn't give us enough time to fix everything that we'd need to fix if we did. :(

Comment: well, then without seeing some code it will be hard to tell...

Comment: @intuitivepixel I'm not asking for a complete solution, I'm just asking about the right way to proceed. :)